# Perl: Slice an array, without creating a whole new array

Tags: performance, perl, slice

I have a reference to an big array, and some of the elements (from some index to the end) need to get used to insert new rows in a DB.

Is there anyway I can create a reference to part of a bigger array?
Or another way I can use a part of a array with DBI's execute_array function, without having Perl copy loads of data in the background?

Here's what I want to do more efficiently:

```
$sh->execute_array({}, [ @{$arrayref}[@indexes] ]);
```

Comment: (oh I see, the args are a list of "columns", where each column is a ref to an array of values for that column.)

Comment: Looks like your Black Mage attack my chicken. ummm... fried chicken...

Comment: I have been wondering. Could I not just do something like: `$arrayref += $index; $sh->execute_array({}, $arrayref);`
I know this exact code will not work as perl is not C, but that does not mean I cannot accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski nope, Perl references are *not* pointers. You could however remove the first element from the referenced array by `shift @$arrayref` (or `splice @$arrayref, 0, $number`), and use the modified array afterwards. This would be quite close to your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sh->execute_array({}, [ @{$arrayref}[@indexes] ]);
```

is similar to

```
sub new_array { my @a = @_; \@a }
$sh->execute_array({}, new_array( @{$arrayref}[@indexes] ));
```

Note the assignment which copies all the elements of the slice. We can avoid copying the scalars as follows:

```
sub array_of_aliases { \@_ }
$sh->execute_array({}, array_of_aliases( @{$arrayref}[@indexes] ));
```

Now, we're just copying pointers (`SV*`) instead of entire scalars (and any string therein).

Comment: So this should work.

And doing some tests the returned reference to an array is for the same elements in the first array (you can change both by changing one element in either of them).

Comment: Slightly more elegant, if you are only doing this once:
    `sub{\@_;}->(@{$arrayref}[2..4]);`

Comment: More compact, maybe, but I purposefully did not use that, for 1) it lacks the self-documenting properties of what I did use, 2) harder to read in a teaching situation, 3) `sub { my @a = @_; \@a }->(...)` would have been even less easy to read, and 4) I figured you'd be using it in more than one place. PS, that `;` is useless.

Answer (score 5):

Array slices return multiple values and have the `@` sigil:

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3, 4);

print join " ", @array[1..2]; # "2 3"

my $aref = [1, 2, 3, 4];

print join " ", @{$aref}[1..3]; # "2 3 4"
```

A slice will return a list (!= an array) of scalars. However, this is not a copy per se:

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3, 4);

for (@array[1..2]) {
  s/\d/_/; # change the element of the array slice
}

print "@array"; # "1 _ _ 4"
```

So this is quite efficient.

If you want to create a new array (or an array reference), you have to copy the values:

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3, 4);

my @slice = @array[1..2];

my $slice = [ @array[1..2] ];
```

The syntax `\@array[1..2]` would return a list of references to each element in the slice, but not a reference *to* the slice.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter passing in Perl starts out as 'pass by reference'.  If you want to know if a value copy is made, look to the source code.

In this case, the definition of `execute_array`'s second line copies the values referenced by `@_` into a lexical named `@array_of_arrays`.

On the bright side, it's a shallow copy.  (at least as far as I've looked.)