# How can I skip elements in Perl list assignment akin to Haskell pattern matching?

Tags: perl, pattern-matching, variable-assignment

In Haskell (and various other functional programming languages), [pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) can be used to assign specific elements of a list while discarding others:

```
Prelude> let [x, _, z] = "abc"
Prelude> x
'a'
Prelude> [z, x]
"ca"
```

Note that ‘`_`’ is not a variable and hasn't been assigned anything:

```
Prelude> _

<interactive>:5:1: Pattern syntax in expression context: _
```

For an Irssi script, written in Perl, I want to do a similar thing and discard the 2<sup>nd</sup> element of ‘`@_`’ (i.e. not assign it to anything):

```
my ($message, _, $windowItem) = @_;
```

This fails with the error message: “`Can't declare constant item in "my" at [...]overlength_filter.pl line 17, near ") ="`”

So what is the Perl equivalent of this underscore wildcard?

Comment: It's hard to search for an answer to this without running into regular expressions. :-/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just assign it to `undef`.

`my ($message, undef, $windowItem) = @_;`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! :-) For what it's worth, here is the finished code: http://lpaste.net/118597

Answer (score 3):

You can also take a slice of the array :)

```
my( $message , $winItem ) = @_[ 0, 2];
```

Comment: Then what happens if I want the first, third, and fifth elements? With `undef` it's obvious. With the slice, would I use `@_[0, 2, 4]`? Anyway, having read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160882/perl-slice-an-array-without-creating-a-whole-new-array), it appears that this slice approach is less efficient, so I consider the `undef` pattern to be better practice in general.

Comment: @JamesHaigh: I think you have misunderstood the question that you link to, and in any case you shouldn't be thinking about speed and efficiency until you have written a program that is as *clear and maintainable* as possible. I personally think the array slice notation is much clearer in general, for instance, `my ($x, $y) = @array[4,9]` versus `my (undef, undef, undef, undef, $x, undef, undef, undef, undef, $y) = @array`

Comment: Borodin: Sure, it's definitely more compact for situations like the example you describe, especially since ‘`undef`’ is 5 characters rather than 1, but if your main aims are _code readability_ and _maintainability_, then this programming pattern with long arrays of arguments probably isn't best practice anyway. Also, you'd probably be better-off using a language better-suited to writing elegant, readable, maintainable code in the first place. I may be biased towards purely-functional programming languages, but even within the imperative paradigm, Python is a good choice for code readability.

Comment: @Borodin: I don't agree that you should not have _any_ consideration of speed and efficiency until the end. I'm not talking about premature optimisation here; I think that it's important to _get in the habit_ of using programming patterns that will avoid much inefficiency straight-off, even though it isn't important here for such a small list. In the worst-case, if you haven't paid _any_ attention to efficiency while writing a program, you may end up with a resource-hog that is flawed by design and requires reïmplementation practically from scratch in order to fix.

Comment: @Borodin: I found that question from the Q/A infobox of [this DDG search](http://ddg.gg/?q=Perl+slice) while trying to understand the format of Perl's slice notation (which, btw., this answer could do with a reference to Perl's documentation on slices), and only skimmed through it. I interpreted “_without creating a whole new array_” and “_without having Perl copy loads of data in the background_” to indicate that when Perl evaluates `@array[@slice]` it actually makes a new array before assigning to the pattern-matched LHS list, which is avoided with the `undef` approach. Is this not the case?

Comment: @JamesHaigh: The meaning there was that the notation `[ @{$arrayref}[@indexes] ]` creates a whole new (anonymous) array. Ignoring the complexity of the expression inside the square brackets, this is similar to `[ @array[0,2] ]`. The array slice expression `@array[0,2]` evaluates to a simple list of values, equivalent to `($array[0], $array[2])`; it is the square brackets -- an anonymous array constructor -- that creates a new array out of that list.

Comment: @Borodin: Ah, _arrays_, not _lists_. But still, one makes a new _array_ out of an array slice, the other makes a new _list_ out of an array slice. Or is this no different anyway because `@array[@slice]` is already having the work of creating a list from the array anyway before assignment? And also, is `[@array[@slice]]` actually making an array out of a list resulting from an array slice?